# Link automated Postman tests with elastic apm report

Tags: elasticsearch, postman, kibana, apm, elastic-apm

I currently have a spring application, in which I have implemented a continuous integration pipeline.
In this pipeline, postman tests are executed automatically.
I would like to add a performance dimension to these tests. So, I set up elastic-apm in my application with an apm server, elasticsearch and kibana.
However, I would like to find a way to link the requests sent by my postman tests to their associated transaction visualization in kibana in order to generate a test performance report

I can't find a way to do this. I've seen that there is a transaction.id or trace.id metadata, but I can't figure out how to use it.

Do you have any idea, even from a "high-level" point of view, how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Try leveraging Opentracing, here is a good example on how to achieve this with Postman: https://hackernoon.com/custom-traceid-in-elastic-apm-82q3uox

Comment: If your CI pipeline is implemented using Jenkins, you might want to take a look at this project developed by Elastic:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/opentelemetry-plugin